# Adapt image movement to window size in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, position

I made an animation on my website which moves if clicked on. The problem is that on the javascript function that manage it, I gave a series of coordinates which fits only if the browser is in full screen. Here are some example:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTJnG.jpg and https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9Bg2.jpg
This is my javascript function:

```
function init(){
   imgObj = document.getElementById('minion');
   immagine = document.getElementById('immagine_minion');
   imgObj.style.position= 'absolute'; 
   imgObj.style.top = '240px';
   imgObj.style.left = '-300px';
   imgObj.style.visibility='hidden';
   appaer();
 }
```

And this, for example, the method which moves it as soon as I open the page:

```
function appaer(){
  immagine.src="../img/minion_dx.png";
  if (parseInt(imgObj.style.left)<200) {
   imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + 5 + 'px';
   imgObj.style.visibility='visible';
   animate = setTimeout(appaer,20);
 } else 
 stop();
}
```

How can I make it fit for every screen resolution?

Comment: What is the intended path of movement? Where should start and stop in relation to content on the page? It seems to me that this could be done with CSS.

Comment: He should walk around that form in the images. It starts from the left corner.

Comment: Like a tour guide?

Comment: Yes man! You're right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should get you started

```js
var stage_number = 0

function go_to_next_stage() {
  stage_number++
  var stage = document.getElementById("stage" + stage_number)
  me.style.left = getComputedStyle(stage).getPropertyValue("left")
  me.style.top = getComputedStyle(stage).getPropertyValue("top")
  if (stage_number > 3) stage_number = 0
}
```

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
  top: 0;
  transition: left 2s, top 2s
}

.stage {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
}

#stage1 {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#stage2 {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#stage3 {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#stage4 {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<img id="me" src="https://de.gravatar.com/userimage/95932142/195b7f5651ad2d4662c3c0e0dccd003b.png?size=100" />
<div onclick="go_to_next_stage()">click anywhere to continue</div>

<div class="stage" id="stage1">
</div>
<div class="stage" id="stage2">
</div>
<div class="stage" id="stage3">
</div>
<div class="stage" id="stage4">
</div>
```